# SWI-Prolog, Read the file and sum the numbers in the file

Tags: file, prolog

I am learning prolog and have the following problem:
Reads an input file, line by line. Then write the sum of each line to the output file.

Given an input.txt input file of the following form:

1 2 7 4 5

3 1 0 7 9

Each entry line are integers separated by a space.

```
? - calculate (‘input.txt’, ’output.txt’).
```

Here is the content of the output.txt file:

19

20

I have tried many ways but still not working, hope someone can help me

Answer (score 0):

```
go :-
    setup_call_cleanup(
        open('output.txt', write, Out),
        forall(file_line_sum('input.txt', Sum), writeln(Out, Sum)),
        close(Out)
    ).


file_line_sum(File, Sum) :-
    file_line(File, Line),
    line_sum(Line, Sum).


line_sum(Line, Sum) :-
    split_string(Line, " ", "", NumsStr),
    maplist(string_number, NumsStr, Nums),
    sum_list(Nums, Sum).


string_number(Str, Num) :-
    number_string(Num, Str).


file_line(File, Line) :-
    setup_call_cleanup(
        open(File, read, In),
        stream_line(In, Line),
        close(In)
    ).


stream_line(In, Line) :-
    repeat,
    read_line_to_string(In, Line1),
    (Line1 == end_of_file -> !, fail ; Line = Line1).
```

Contents of input.txt:

```
1 2 7 4 5
3 1 0 7 9
123 456 7890
```

Result in swi-prolog:

```
?- time(go).
% 115 inferences, 0.001 CPU in 0.001 seconds (90% CPU, 195568 Lips)
```

Generated output.txt:

```
19
20
8469
```